# Ausencia del primer registro de la tabla al llenar un Treeview con el resultado de una consulta

Tags: python, postgresql, tkinter

Aun soy novato en Python y me ha surgido un problema que no se solucionar. Estoy creando un formulario para alimentar/ver/modificar... registros de una base de datos en PostgreSQL y entre otras opciones quiero volcar los datos de la base de datos a un ***Treeview*** (`tabla1`) para verlos en forma de tabla.

El caso es que tal como está mi código funciona bien, pero con una incidencia, y es que me **omite la primera linea de la base de datos**. Llevo días tratando de localizar el error y no se dónde está.

Este es el código:

```
def vertablaentera():
    tabla=cajan.get()
    while tabla!="familia" and tabla!="telefonos":
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Administrador","La tabla introducida es erronea")
        cajan.delete(0,END)
        break
    if tabla=="familia":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM familia")
        verRegistros=cursor.fetchone()
        #la linea anterior utiliza fetchone y no fetchall porque el bucle de abajo recorre uno a uno los registros
        if not verRegistros:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Administrador","No existen datos")
        else:
            #tkMessageBox.showinfo("INFORMACIO SOLICITADA",verRegistros)
            id=0
            for row in cursor:
                tabla1.insert("",index="end",text=str(id),value=(row[1],row[2],row[3]))
                id+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si iteras sobre `cursor` total o parcialmente con un `for`, o usas `fetchone`/`fetchmany`/`fetchall` "consumes" esos elementos, de forma que una  posterior iteración empezará por donde quedó la anterior y solo retornará los resultados restantes. Cuando haces `verRegistros=cursor.fetchone()` estas consumiendo el primer resultado de la consulta, de forma que el `for` siguiente empieza por la segunda fila.

Hay varias formas de resolver esto, desde permitir el scroll sobre el cursor, usar `rowcount` para saber si la consulta retorna sin datos (aunque no siempre es posible), llenar primero el `treeview` y luego comprobar si está vacío, usar `fetchall`, etc. Sin embargo, creo que la opción más simple es  agregar esta fila al `treeview` antes del `for`:

```
def vertablaentera():
    tabla=cajan.get()
    while tabla!="familia" and tabla!="telefonos":
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Administrador","La tabla introducida es erronea")
        cajan.delete(0,END)
        break
    if tabla=="familia":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM familia")
        verRegistros=cursor.fetchone()
        #la linea anterior utiliza fetchone y no fetchall porque el bucle de abajo recorre uno a uno los registros
        if not verRegistros:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Administrador","No existen datos")
        else:
            #tkMessageBox.showinfo("INFORMACIO SOLICITADA",verRegistros)

            tabla1.insert("", index="end", text="0",
                          value=(verRegistros[1], verRegistros[2], verRegistros[3]))

            id=1
            for row in cursor:
                tabla1.insert("", index="end", text=str(id),
                              value=(row[1], row[2], row[3]))
                id += 1
```

Comment: Genial! No era capaz de ver mi error.